# how to add a class to the select field in multishipper (addresses.phtml) without editing the core

Tags: forms, core

hi i want to add a class to the select field in the multishipper addresses.phtml screen. the function is

```
 echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect($_item, $_index)
```

that is calling the select with addresses droplist. 
this function is found in Addresses.php

```
  public function getAddressesHtmlSelect($item, $index)
    {
        $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
            ->setName('ship['.$index.']['.$item->getQuoteItemId().'][address]')
            ->setId('ship_'.$index.'_'.$item->getQuoteItemId().'_address')
            ->setValue($item->getCustomerAddressId())
            ->setOptions($this->getAddressOptions());

        return $select->getHtml();
    }
```

i thought that the options would work because the select field is generated with the class attribute empty.

i tried the following syntax $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect($_item, $_index, 'form-control') without success..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class through `javsscript` by `element id` in your `template (phtml)` file. This is the only method to add class in your select box, without changing the core files and rewrite the block.

```
<script>
     $('id-of-your-select-box').addClassName('yourclass');
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, i was suspecting this. i just cant believe how badly designed that is. we should not have to resort to javascript to create markup.

Comment: Then you have to rewrite that block

Comment: yeah, i get it. i just think its badly designed. you shouldnt have to spend hours rewriting a block in order to add a class. and you shouldnt have to do it with js as your alternative. thanks for the info